# How to physically disable the "large load" option on a washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine, washer, load

My old washing machine has 4 options (with the highest setting to be "large load"). How can I physically disable the dial in such a way that the large load will no longer be an option for the users?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Drainage issue, large load may cause floor drain backup.

Comment: One option that comes to mind is to insert a screw into the machine faceplate between the spindle and the markings, then screw a corresponding screw into the dial, either from the side or the top. Of course, you'd probably want to use some sort of security screw for the one on the dial. Alternatively, if you're really, really good at electronics, you may be able to remove the faceplate and disconnect the lead for the large load setting.

Comment: You don't need to be *that* good at electronics.   However, **fix the drainage issue**.  You think this *isn't* going to get worse? Of course it will, and then you'll be disabling "medium" etc.

Comment: I *am* also fixing the drainage issue.

Comment: @KubiK888: Then don't bother with the knob. Communicate with the people who will use the machine (I imagine there's only a couple such folk), post a post-it note on it as a reminder, and that will suffice until your drainage issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

somewhere in the back there is a pin which limits the rotation of the shaft. move the pin and the number of options will be reduced. (some unknown amount of dissasembly will be required)

or you could add a pin to the back of the knob and cut an arc in the panel to accomodate it.